# MacOS Server: Volume … not responding

Tags: macos, server.app, disk-volume

I have recently installed MacOS Server on my iMac running Sierra 10.12.4. I am getting an occasional alert that a Volume is not responding.

The message is of the form:

```
Volume "…" not responding
```

I now have 4 such messages, but the id of the volume keeps changing. I don’t think I have so many volumes attached, so I can’t work out what’s going on.

- how can I discover more about a particular volume from the id?
- why would it keep changing?

Comment: We need some more context like where you are seeing the message,  a few samples of the changing volume id, etc.  Can you please post the *exact" messages you are seeing?

Comment: @Allan In the Alerts Section of the Server App. `Volume "7B84793E-1261-4B45-A4F1-118E5F251463" not responding`. The summary:  `The volume "7B84793E-1261-4B45-A4F1-118E5F251463" is no longer accessible. Loss of this volume may affect services or applications on the server.`

Answer (score 1):

The Mac OS X Server disk watcher is pretty sensitive, and it seems to get triggered by apfs volume snapshot notifications (they will have "@-snap" in their names). It may also trigger on mobile time machine volume unmounts which as I recall looks like a uuid. If it is not a volume name that you recognize, I would not worry.

Comment: I get similar error messages but no "@-snap" in the name. I think it could be due to the google-drive which is not responding. I didn't have this message before installing the Drive.